# Is there a type that includes both: List<T> and also HashSet<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, hashset

I have two methods that display: one a List of items and one a HashSet of items. The methods are identical. Is there a way to write the method with a parameter type so that I can use the same method regardless of the type of the argument passed to the method: `List<T>` or `HashSet<T>`?

The methods are:

```
    public static void DisplayList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
            if (i < list.Count - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(", ");
            }
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void DisplayHashSet<T>(HashSet<T> set)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in set)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
            if (i < set.Count - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(", ");
            }
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: If you use `i != 0` to put a comma *before* the item, you don’t need `Count` and can be as flexible as [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) by accepting `IEnumerable<T>`. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface:

```
public static void DisplayHashSet<T>(ICollection<T> col)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in col)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString());
        if (i < col.Count - 1)
        {
            Console.Write(", ");
        }
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't have Count, you need to use System.Linq get the IEnumerable count `enumerable.Count()`

Comment: `ICollection` looks better here

Answer (score 5):

According to [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) and [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) documentation both implement [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) and [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.8), you can use any of these interfaces because they have `Count` property.

Since you aren't modifying the collection, only displaying it, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` looks better here

```cs
public static void DisplayCollection<T>(IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString());
        if (i < collection.Count - 1)
        {
            Console.Write(", ");
        }
        i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

However, if you'll need just a string representation of collection, [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) method with overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to do that in one line

```cs
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var display = string.Join(", ", list);
Console.WriteLine(display);
```

The code above will print `1, 2, 3, 4`, which is the same with `DisplayCollection<T>` method above

Comment: Thank you very much! 1. I did not mention that I use Visual Studio  2010 and probably therefore I do not know the IReadOnlyCollection<T> type. 2. The displayString is a very nice idea I did noth think about.

Comment: @user2102327 `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` was added in .NET 4.5, it doesn't related to your version of Visual Studio, it's about target framework of your application. You can use `ICollection<T>`, which was added in .NET 2.0. `string.Join` is available from .NET 1.1, afaik